# libsystem_sim_c.dylib`__stack_chk_fail:

Tags: ios, runtime-error

I have a custom UILABEL that returns the word touched. Sometimes the word triggers a segue. The label had been working fine, until yesterday when certain touches started causing app crash. All touches do not cause a crash unless they 1) they are on the 2nd line of the uilabel (not the first) and 2) they trigger a segue. However, the exception is raised before a segue is ever triggered

The debug console does not yield an error. Instead it highlights these three lines of code:

```
NSString *tappedString = [label getWordContainingCharacterAtIndex:charIndex];

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (!self.lastTouches) {
        return;
    }

    self.lastTouches = nil;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CFIndex index = [self characterIndexAtPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    if (![self.delegate label:self didEndTouch:touch onCharacterAtIndex:index]) {//THREAD 1 : signal SIGABRT
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

The other notable thread in the spool is

```
[UIWindow_sendTouchesFoeEvent:], which is paused on 0x1bf860a:  movl   %edi, 0x10(%esp)
```

When I hit continue I get

```
libsystem_sim_c.dylib`__stack_chk_fail:
```

Also in thread 1
And I get

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Can you show the code for `characterIndexAtPoint`?  Treating a CFIndex as a Bool is a bit suspicious. Typically a method like this would return -1 or NSNotFound

Comment: Sorry @Paulw11 , treating CFIndex as bool was part of my error testing, it is not contributing to current error

Comment: The exception indicates that you have run over the end of an allocation on the stack, which is why I suspect the value of `index`.  Does the exception occur on a device as well as the simulator?  What if you use `NSInteger` instead of `CFIndex`?

Comment: @Paulw11changing the code algorithm to less resource intense sorting method solved the problem, I otherwise don't know what happened. Thanks very much for your help